Why quantum fluctuation during inflation contributes to structure formation and how it sets the initial condition?
I'm trying to understand the role of the inflaton condensate and quantum fluctuations during inflation and how they evolve into the large-scale structure we observe today. Here's where I’m getting stuck and would love some clarity.
First off, the inflaton during inflation seems to be this smooth, classical field driving the expansion. However, there are quantum fluctuations riding on top of this classical field configuration, which are stretched by inflation to superhorizon scales. Once these fluctuations become superhorizon, they freeze, but are they still part of the condensate? Or are they entirely separate? How do these fluctuations behave in relation to the condensate, if I can call the state condensate?
When we talk about superhorizon modes, they’re outside the Hubble radius, meaning they’re not causally connected and experience the full effect of expansion. I’d expect the expansion to dilute the density, but surprisingly, the perturbations themselves stay fairly constant during this time. They don’t shrink away, but instead undergo a quantum-to-classical transition as they freeze on superhorizon scales. How should I think of this? There was this post on horizon exit that suggested particles go outside the comoving horizon and become causally disconnected. So, can I interpret this as the inflaton condensate becoming causally disconnected in a similar way, such that no causal evolution can alter the state of these fluctuations during inflation?
Now, my understanding of particle creation in quantum field theory is that it depends on defining the vacuum, usually by quantizing around $\phi=0$. However, in the case of inflation, the inflaton field is not at $\phi=0$, so this raises a big question for me. Perhaps, it is wrong to think of the superhorizon fluctuations as particles being created during inflation, or is there another interpretation that fits better? Even in case of Higgs mechanism, we first perform the shifting and then expand around that minima and quantize the perturbation. Here, we are expanding about the classically dynamic background and quantizing them.
Once inflation ends and reheating begins, the inflaton condensate (+perturbation?) decays into particles, and the hot plasma forms. We know that the modes which left the horizon during inflation are re-entering later, but what does this mode do, after entering the horizon? How do they set up the oscillation? Everything seems so lost in mathematics, that I miss physics and intuition for what's happpening.
I could have thought of this process as production of inhomogeneity, then breaking the causal contact between the inhomogeneity due to rapid expansion. Once the inflation ended, the inhomegeneity could influence each other causally, the began evolving and we get into the photon-baryon plasma and set up the baryonic acoustic oscillations. I understand that these are driven by sound waves in the plasma, with gravity pulling matter together and pressure from photons pushing it apart. Is it the right way to interpret the whole process?
There are so many parts of this process I’m unsure about, especially the transition from quantum fluctuations to classical perturbations and how they to interpret these superhorizon fluctuations. Any clarification on these points would be really helpful.

You are right to be puzzled about any transition from "quantum fluctuations" (as they are called, but I think the name is misleading) to classical perturbations. There are various elements to this and I am not knowledgeable about all of them. What I have seen in calculations is that people obtain quantities such as correlation coefficients for a quantum field, and then assert that the end product is a classical field whose inhomogeneity (i.e. density fluctuations etc.) has statistical properties that match the statistics implied by the quantum correlation coefficients. However, exactly what is the nature of such a quantum-to-classical transition is, I think, never quite spelled out. It seems to me to be highly reminiscent of the quantum measurement problem and the Schrodinger cat thought-experiment.
I think it appropriate to note also that this area of physics is not quite as settled as its proponents mostly imply. Although many very able theoretical physicists are convinced of the broad correctness of the inflation concept, I think it has not yet been shown to reduce, compared to other scenarios, the degree of fine-tuning which has to be assumed in the initial conditions in order that the model shall describe our universe. This suggests that other early-universe models, which do not necessarily involve inflation, remain candidates equally worthy of our attention.

The first paragraph on quantum to classical transition is all I needed to hear. Now, I understand what we do, however I still don't get, what do we mean by horizon exit and horizon entry in terms of particle picture?

I can't answer this follow-up precisely without doing some mugging-up. But I recall that another pitfall in this area is that people often muddle the usage of terms such as "horizon". Beware in case they really mean Hubble distance. In some presentations "exit" and "entry" might refer, for example, to ratio of wavelength to Hubble distance (i.e. poor terminology).
